# Сохранение изображения в директории с помощью React js

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch, photo

У меня в проекте реализован некий каталог который берёт изображения из директории на фронте, реализованном на реакте, также есть бэк написанный на PHP, я реализовал этот каталог так - JSON массив с бэка отсылается на фронт, а внутри я использую названия изображений, уже лежащих на фронте, в целом это работает, пока я не захочу удалить или добавить товар в каталоге, мне нужно знать, как можно обрабатывать локальные директории через React JS, можно отсылать изображения из бэка, но и тут я не очень понимаю как мне обрабатывать поступающие файлы, можете меня как-то направить на нужный путь, ссылку на то, как можно менять локальные файлы или как принимать и обрабатывать полученные изображения.

Comment: не локальные, а серверные. Фронт отсылает файл на сервер, сервер обрабатывает запрос. Аналогично с удалением.

Comment: У меня нет обмена изображений с сервером, есть уже загруженные файлы на фронт, которые достаются из локалки при надобности, мне кажется, что слишком много требуется для пересылки изображений напрямую с сервера. Не знаю как все делают, подозреваю, что они просто отправляют изображения с бэка и отображают их, но я хотел бы сделать немного легче для сервера, да и сам сайт так быстрее работать будет

Comment: у вас фронт находится на локальном ПК? А как он попадает другим клиентам на ПК ( в частности как попадают ваши локальные файлы на ПК других клиентов)?